# Reading mixed values from a file and storing them in a structure array

Tags: c

I'm working on a homework and facing some Problems.

I need to read from a file which contains numbers and strings and store the values in an array.

The txt file I'm reading from is like the following

```
    50090607;ApoBank Frankfurt Main
    51220800;Banco do Brasil Frankfurt
    10020500;Bank fur Sozialwirtschaft
    66090800;BBBank Karlsruhe
    10000000;BBk Berlin
```

I wrote this code but it seems not to work.

```
 //IBAN.c

typedef struct {
  int banknumber;
  char bankname[50];
} Bankdata;

int main(void) {

  FILE *BLZ1;
  Bankdata *Bank;
  int i = 0;
  int size = 10;

  Bank = (Bankdata*) malloc(sizeof(Bankdata) * size);
  BLZ1 = fopen("BLZ1.txt", "r");
  if (BLZ1 == NULL) {
    printf("File not found");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (!feof(BLZ1)) {

    fscanf(BLZ1, "%d;%50[^\n]\n", Bank[i].banknumber, Bank[i].bankname);
    printf("%d , %s\n", Bank[i].banknumber, Bank[i].bankname);
    i++;
    if (i >= size) {
      size += 10;
      Bank = realloc(Bank, sizeof(Bankdata) * size);
    }
  }
  fclose(BLZ1);

  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Further `"%d;%49[^\n]"` (do not include `'\n'` at the end) and you must limit the characters to allow space for `'\0'`. You must always validate the return of `fscanf` (`== 2` in your case)

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Given OP's weak usage of `while (!feof(BLZ1)){`, having a white-space after `"%d;%49[^\n]"` makes sense to cause the end-of-file flag on the next `feof()`.  Still better to use `fscanf()` return value.  Best to use `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux -- but doesn't that leave him open to an *input failure* if non-POSIX line-ending on final line of input?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No. A white-space  in a scanf format never fails. C11 §7.21.6.2 8

Comment: Ahh, whitespace is just zero or more whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save time. Enable all complier warnings.

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

The `*printf` specifier `"%d"` expects a matching `int`. But this is not `printf()`.
The `*scanf` specifier `"%d"` expects a matching `int *`, not an `int`.

```
    // fscanf(BLZ1, "%d;%50[^\n]\n", Bank[i].banknumber, Bank[i].bankname);
    fscanf(BLZ1, "%d;%49[^\n]\n", &Bank[i].banknumber, Bank[i].bankname);
    //    Add & here -------------^
```

Also:  Use 49 to limit the scanning to 49 characters, allowing those 49 and the *null character* to be saved in `char bankname[50];`  [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121909/reading-mixed-values-from-a-file-and-storing-them-in-a-structure-array/54122179#comment95075781_54121909)

---

Advanced issues:

Better code would test the return value from `fscanf()`, than use `feof()`.

```
// while (!feof(BLZ1)){
while (fscanf(BLZ1, "%d;%49[^\n]\n" , &Bank[i].banknumber , Bank[i].bankname) == 2) {
  printf("%d , %s\n" , Bank[i].banknumber , Bank[i].bankname);
  i++;
  if (i >= size){
    size +=10;
    Bank = realloc(Bank , sizeof(Bankdata)*size);
  }
}
```

The final `"\n"` in `"%d;%49[^\n]\n"` is OK, but not needed here.

With *line* orientated data, best to read the *line* with `fgets()` and then parse it.  Much easier to cope with malformed input.